# C++ for loop style to invoke specific member function of object

Tags: c++, stl

To iterate a array to invoke the specific method of each element.

(a). Index Style

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < my_objs.size(); i++)
{
    my_objs[i].do_something();
}
```

(b). Iterator style

```
for(std::vector<MyObject>::const_iterator iter = my_objs.begin();
    iter != my_objs.end(); iter++)
{
    iter->do_something();
}
```

(c). STL Style

```
std::for_each(my_objs.begin(), my_objs.end(), [](const MyObject& obj){ obj.do_something(); });
```

(d). C++ 11 for-loop style

```
for(const auto& obj: my_objs)
{
    obj.do_something();
}
```

Many C++ books told me, use STL whenever you can. But compared (c) to (d), the STL style for-loop need additional `iterator pair` and the `parameter type definition` of lambda so that the `std::for_each` becomes too long to read easily. It looks the (d) way is more clearer and less types.

Which one has the better readability? or any better style to represent that to invoke the member function of each object in a vector?

Comment: "most books" recommend a lambda? didn't realize there were so many books up to date :)

Comment: (e). C++17 style: `for(obj: my_objs) {obj.do_something();}` If you want to use that in C++11, it's `auto&&` rather than `const auto&`.

Comment: @Matt I should change `most` to `many`.

Comment: C++1z style: `for(obj : my_objs) obj.do_something();`

Comment: Is your book pre-C++11?

Comment: Yeah, some of books I read are pre-c++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithmic style may be appropriate if you have a very simple task such as calling a nullary member function:

```
std::for_each(my_objs.cbegin(), my_objs.cend(),
              std::mem_fn(&MyObject::do_something));
```

Otherwise feel free to use the range-based loop, which is perfectly acceptable for small units of work. As always use your judgement and refactor when you find that any one block is doing too much work.

Comment: That's cleaner done with a range-based for-loop, especially the C++1z one.

Comment: Use array of object + for_each + mem_fn looks more clearer to tell a reader you wanna invoke a method of object in array. 
Thanks!